# Switch Programming Language

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, switch-statement

I've forgotten how to switch programming languages in Visual Studio 2008.  I need to switch from C++ to C#.  Help!

Comment: have you got VS 2008 for C# installed? sorry I'm using the individual packages (Express Editions) so I install them one by one - and there's no switch for that.

Comment: Need more clues to solve this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to switch the key-mappings ?
`Main menu > Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`
Use the dropdown that says Apply keyboard mapping scheme.. to switch from C++ to C#

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose Tools -> Import and Export Settings...
2. Select Reset All Settings and click Next
3. Select whether you would like to save the current settings and click Next
4. Select the settings you want to use and click Finish

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Just to explain further, when I first installed Visual Studio, it asked which programming language I wanted to use.  I set it to Visual C++.  Now I want to change that setting to Visual C#.  Your answer seems right, so I'll try that.